# return false doesnt seem to work in this javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

I have a onclick function,

```
$("#mymodal").on("click",".close",function() {
    checkpincode();
    checkzipcode();
});
```

and fn checkpincode returns false but the execution still continues and my checkzipcode function gets executed. Any ideas why this behavior??

Comment: A return false within `checkpincode()` only causes that function to return. On returning, execution control is returned to the calling scope, which in this case is your click callback. So `checkzipcode()` gets called as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need

```
$("#mymodal").on("click",".close",function() {
    if(!checkpincode()){
        return false;
    }
    checkzipcode();
});
```

or

```
$("#mymodal").on("click",".close",function() {
    checkpincode() && checkzipcode()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` value from `checkpincode()` is passed to calling statement in `click` handler and does not mean it will cause return of function from which `checkpincode()` is invoked.  You can use `if` statement to conditionally execute the checkzipcode() function.

```
$("#mymodal").on("click",".close",function() {
    if(checkpincode())
       checkzipcode();
});
```

For more understand you can assign value returned form `checkpincode()` and use it for calling `checkzipcode()`;

```
$("#mymodal").on("click",".close",function() {
    result = checkpincode();  
    if(result)
       checkzipcode();
    //return result; //if you want.
});
```